# 2-bit mapping using bitwise operations in C

Tags: c, mapping, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

This is my first question, so I hope to do this right.

I have a problem where I have to map a key which can be in the range (0, 1, 2) to select a value from the same range (0, 1, 2). I have to repeat this millions of times and I was trying to implement this by using bitwise operations in C, without success.

So let's say I have 16 keys in the range (0, 1, 2) which I want to map to 16 values in the same range by using the following rules:

```
0 -> 2
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
```

I can represent the array of 16 keys as 16 2-bit pairs in a 32bit unsigned int. For instance:

```
  0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, ... //Original array of keys
 00 01 10 01 10 00 ...  //2-bit pairs representation of keys in a 32bit int
```

and I am interested in transforming the unsigned int, following the rules above (i.e. the 2-bit pairs have to be transformed following the rules: 00->10, 01->01, and 10->01), so that I end up with a 32bit unsigned int like:

```
 10 01 01 01 01 10 ...  //2-bit pairs transformed using the given rule.
```

Would it be a relatively fast bitwise procedure which will allow me to apply efficiently this transformation (given that the transformation rules can change)?

I hope I formulated my question clearly. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I corrected some mistakes, and clarified some points following comments.

EDIT2: Following some suggestions, I add what I hope is a code example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    int i;

    unsigned int keys[16];
    unsigned int bitKeys = 0;

    unsigned int mapping[3];

    unsigned int result[16];
    unsigned int bitResults = 0;

    //Initialize random keys and mapping dict    
    for(i = 0; i<16; i++) 
        keys[i] = rand() % 3;
        bitKeys |= keys[i] << (2*i);

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++) 
        mapping[i] = rand() % 3; 

    //Get results without using bitwise opperations.
    for(i = 0; i<16; i++) 
        result[i] = mapping[ keys[i] ];
        bitResults |= result[i] << (2*i);


    //Would it be possible to get bitResults directly from bitKeys efficiently by using bitwise operations?


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: " I was trying to implement this by using bitwise operations, without success." please show your code ([mcve]). And please pick one language

Comment: 00->11 is 0 -> 3

Comment: Will the map always be 0→2, 1→1, 2→1, or can it be different?

Comment: @Eraklon Thanks, it was a mistake, I corrected this.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I do not have any bitwise code, do you mean an example using standard C way of doing it? (Edit: I also added the language, following your suggestion)

Comment: @EricPostpischil It can be different, and change. Although I would be happy if I can generate somehow an independent implementation for each case.

Comment: leave mirco optimizations to the compiler. Maybe a naive implementation will already do its job. Hence if you have some code I would suggest to show it. In the question you wrote that you made an attempt, now you say you have no code. Whatever you have it would be good to include it in the quesiton

Comment: How set are you on using 32-bit values? If you treat it as 16 8-bit values, it's pretty easy to do with SSE intrinsics....

Comment: @idclev463035818: That is not good advice. I would not expect compilers to have significant optimizations for the task of applying a map to each two-bits of a 32-bit number, but considerable optimizations are available via bitwise operations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil maybe I should been more careful with wording. What I wanted to say is that to speculate about possible compiler optimizations one should look at the code. Even if it is just for reference I would start with something naive and simple

Comment: @Superlokkus - This question is just as applicable, and can be just as well answered using `C++` as it can be in `C`.  This is one of those times where tagging both languages is acceptable.

Comment: The sample map in the question can be implemented with `uint32_t y = x | x>>1; y &= 0x55555555; return (y ^ 0x55555555) << 1 | y;`. The map space is small enough that it may be reasonable to generate expressions for all possibilities and look them up at run-time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Why is your last comment not posted as an answer instead of being hidden in the comments?

Comment: @ryyker: It is not complete.

Comment: @ryyker I don't find this practicable, while both languages share some concepts and there is code both legal C and C++ code, I can not even simply determine if I can use `std::bitset` in my answer of not. So I don't see any advantage for labeling both, except if the answer would explictly require C and C++ legal solutions. But the OP mentions C explictly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your comment. Yes, it will be reasonable to implement an expression for each case. Do you have an idea, or point me to some kind of formalism, that I could use to generate all the expressions in some sort of systematic way?

Comment: @Superlokkus I think it has to be C.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I added some example code I hope it helps to clarify. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for your comment, I cannot use SSE or other SIMD extensions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I found a general answer. I posted it here, and I thought that you may be interested in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a problem of simplifying truth tables to minimal Boolean expressions; here we need two expressions, one for each output value bit.

```
BA QP

00 10
01 01
10 01
11 XX
```

B: high key bit, A: low key bit, Q: high value bit, P: low value bit

By using any of the many tools available (including our brain) for minimizing [combinational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic) circuits, we get the expressions

```
Q = ¬A·¬B
P = A + B
```

Now that we have the expressions, we can apply them to all keys in a 32-bit variable:

```
    uint32_t keys = 2<<30|0<<10|1<<8|2<<6|1<<4|2<<2|0;  // for example
    uint32_t vals = ~keys & ~keys<<1 & 0xAAAAAAAA   // value_high is !key_high & !key_low
                  | (keys>>1 | keys) & 0x55555555;  // value_low is key_high | key_low
```

> I would need a solution for any arbitrary mapping.

Here's an example program for arbitrary mappings. For each of the two value bits, there are 2<sup>3</sup> possible expressions (the same set for both bits); these expressions are:

```
0    ¬A·¬B    A    ¬B    B    ¬A    A+B    1
```

By concatenating the high and low mapping bits, respectively, for keys 0, 1 and 2, we get the index of the expression corresponding to the mapping function. In the following program, the values of all the expressions, even the ones unused by the mapping, are stored in the `term` array. While this may seem wasteful, it allows computation without branches, which may be a win in the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    unsigned mapping[3];
    // generate example mapping
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) mapping[i] = rand() % 3, printf(" %d->%d", i, mapping[i]);
    puts("");

    // determine the mapping expression index 0..7 for high and low value bit
    short h = mapping[0]/2 | mapping[1]/2<<1 | mapping[2]/2<<2;
    short l = mapping[0]%2 | mapping[1]%2<<1 | mapping[2]%2<<2;

    uint32_t keys = 0x1245689A; // for example

    uint32_t b = keys, a = keys<<1;
    uint32_t term[8] = { 0, ~a&~b, a, ~b, b, ~a, a|b, -1 };  // all possible terms
    uint32_t vals = term[h]    & 0xAAAAAAAA   // value_high
                  | term[l]>>1 & 0x55555555;  // value_low
    printf("%8x\n%8x\n", keys, vals);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I put a particular mapping as an example, but I would need a solution for any arbitrary mapping.

Comment: @Oriol Canela Xandri - I amended the answer.

Comment: Many thanks for extending your answer! I looks like a nice solution. Thinking about this overnight, I also found an alternative approach which does not require to define something like _term_. I am not sure if I should post it as an alternative answer, or in the comment or in the original question?

Comment: @Oriol Canela Xandri - If your approach also solves the problem, you shouldn't hide it in a comment (where code formatting is limited), but rather not hesitate to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it, and using some of the ideas from other answers, I think I found a general solution. It is based in first estimating the value assuming there are only the keys 10, and 01 (i.e. one bit of the pair determines the other) and then correct by the key 00. An example code of the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void printBits(size_t const size, void const * const ptr)
{
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) ptr;
    unsigned char byte;
    int i, j;

    for (i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for (j=7;j>=0;j--)
        {
            byte = (b[i] >> j) & 1;
            printf("%u", byte);
            if(j%2 == 0) printf("|");
        }
    }
    puts("");
}

int test2BitMapping(unsigned int * mapping)
{
    int i;

    unsigned int keys[16];
    unsigned int bitKeys = 0;

    unsigned int b = 0;
    unsigned int c = 0;
    unsigned int d = 0;
    unsigned int expand[4] = {0x00000000u, 0x55555555u, 0xAAAAAAAAu, 0xFFFFFFFFu};
    unsigned int v12 = 0;
    unsigned int v0mask = 0;

    unsigned int result[16];
    unsigned int bitResults = 0;
    unsigned int bitResultsTest = 0;

    //Create mapping masks
    b = ((1 & mapping[1]) | (2 & mapping[2]));
    c = (2 & mapping[1]) | (1 & mapping[2]);
    d = mapping[0];

    b = expand[b];
    c = expand[c];
    d = expand[d];

    //Initialize random keys
    for(i = 0; i<16; i++) {
        if(0) { //Test random keys
            keys[i] = rand() % 3;
        }
        else { //Check all keys are generated
            keys[i] = i % 3;
        }
        bitKeys |= keys[i] << (2*i);
    }

    //Get results without using bitwise opperations.
    for(i = 0; i<16; i++) {
        result[i] = mapping[ keys[i] ];
        bitResultsTest |= result[i] << (2*i);
    }

    //Get results by using bitwise opperations.
    v12 = ( bitKeys & b ) | ( (~bitKeys) & c );
    v0mask = bitKeys | (((bitKeys & 0xAAAAAAAAu) >> 1) | ((bitKeys & 0x55555555u) << 1));
    bitResults = ( d & (~v0mask) ) | ( v12 & v0mask );


    //Check results
    if(0) {
        for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            printf("%d -> %d, ", i, mapping[i]); 
        }
        printf("\n"); 
        printBits(sizeof(unsigned int), &bitKeys);
        printBits(sizeof(unsigned int), &bitResults);
        printBits(sizeof(unsigned int), &bitResultsTest);
        printf("-------\n");
    }
    if(bitResults != bitResultsTest) {
        printf("*********\nDifferent\n*********\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("OK\n");
    }
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    int i, j, k;
    unsigned int mapping[3];

    //Test using random mapping
    for(k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
        for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            mapping[i] = rand() % 3; 
        }
        test2BitMapping(mapping);
    }

    //Test all possible mappings
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            for(k = 0; k<3; k++) {
                mapping[0] = i;
                mapping[1] = j;
                mapping[2] = k; 

                test2BitMapping(mapping);
            }
        }
    }


    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> and I am interested in transforming the unsigned int, following the rules above (i.e. the 2-bit pairs have to be transformed following the rules: 00->10, 01->01, and 10->01), so that I end up with a 32bit unsigned int

Certainly this can be done, but the required sequence of operations will be different for each of the 27 distinct mappings from { 0, 1, 2 } to { 0, 1, 2 }.  Some can be very simple, such as for the three constant mappings, but others require more complex expressions.

Without having performed a thorough analysis, I'm inclined to guess that the mappings that are neither constant nor permutations, such as the one presented in the example, probably have the greatest minimum complexity.  These all share the characteristic that two keys map to the same value, whereas the other key maps to a different one.  One way -- not necessarily the best -- to approach finding an expression for such a mapping is to focus first on achieving the general result that the two keys map to one value and the other to a different one, and then move on to transforming the resulting values to the desired ones, if necessary.

For the example presented, for instance,

> ```
> 0 -> 2
> 1 -> 1
> 2 -> 1
> ```

, one could (on a per-key basis) use `((key & 2) >> 1) | ((key & 1) << 1)` to achieve these preliminary results:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 3
2 -> 3
```

, which can be converted to the desired final result by flipping the higher-order bit via an exclusive-or operation.

Note well the bit masking.  There are other ways that could be approached for mapping a single key, but for the case of multiple keys stored in contiguous bits of the same integer, you need to be careful to avoid contaminating the computed mappings with data from different keys.

In 16-entry bit-vector form, that would be

```
uint32_t keys = /*...*/;
uint32_t values = (((keys & 0xAAAAAAAAu) >> 1) | ((keys & 0x55555555u) << 1))
        ^ 0xAAAAAAAAu;
```

. That happens to have a couple fewer operations than the expression in your other answer so far, but I am not certain that it is the smallest possible number of operations.  In fact, if you are prepared to accept *arithmetic* operations in addition to bitwise ones, then you can definitely do it with fewer operations:

```
uint32_t keys = /*...*/;
uint32_t values = 0xAAAAAAAAu
        - (((keys & 0xAAAAAAAAu) >> 1) | (keys & 0x55555555u));
```

Of course, in general, various operations do not all have the same cost as each other, but integer addition and subtraction and bitwise AND, OR, and XOR all have the the same cost as each other on most architectures (see, for example, https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and taking the time to write it. That sounds a good starting point. I can certainly use arithmetic operations, but I was afraid that it may be easier with them to contaminate (as you already indicated) the neighboring bits. Anyway, I think that your answer can point me to the right direction on how to address this problem. I will mark it as the accepted answer, unless somebody gives a better one.

Comment: Just an update, your answer inspired me for finding a general solution. I posted it as an answer here. I let you know, just in case you may be interested. Thanks for your help.